# How can i make a delete Button to remove the bookmark form the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

What I'm doing now is a form takes the website name and the URL. When I click on the submit button, the output is the name of the website and two buttons:
 1. one to visit
 2. remove the bookmark `onClick`

Unfortunately I can't make the remove button function:

```
<!DOCTYPEhtml>
<htmllang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>JSBOOKMARK</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index_style.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container pt-5 pb-5">
        <h1 class="pb-5 pl-3 font-weight-bold">BookMark</h1>
        <hr>
        <div class="body m-auto text-center py-5">
            <h2 class="py-2">Bookmark your favorite sites</h2>
            <form class="w-75 m-auto" id="myForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Site_Name" class="py-2">Site Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="siteName" placeholder="Bookmark Name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Site_URL" class="py-2">Site URL</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="siteUrl" placeholder="website URL" required>
                </div>
                <button id="sub" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="container mt-3">
            <div class="row shadow-none p-3 mb-5 bg-light rounded">
 <!--dispalyarea-->
                <div class="col">
                    <div id="bookmarkCon"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>&copy;2019 Bookmarker Inc.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

//Java script code :

var bookMname = document.getElementById("siteName");
var bookUrl = document.getElementById("siteUrl");
var btn = document.getElementById("sub");
var bookMarks = [];

btn.onclick = function () {
    addBookMark();
    displayData();
    reset();

}

function addBookMark() {
    var bookMark = {
        bookMarkName: bookMname.value,
        url: bookUrl.value,
    }

    bookMarks.push(bookMark);

}

function displayData() {

    /**local var */
    var data = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < bookMarks.length; i++) {

        data += "<div><span class='mr-5 font-weight-bold h1 text-uppercase'>" + bookMarks[i].bookMarkName + "  " + "</span><span>" + ' <a class="btn btn-primary mr-4" target="_blank" href="' + bookMarks[i].url + '">Visit</a> ' + "</span></div>"

    }

    document.getElementById("bookmarkCon").innerHTML = data;
}

function displayData() {

    /**local var */
    var data = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < bookMarks.length; i++) {

        data += "<div><span class='mr-5 font-weight-bold h1 text-uppercase'>" +    bookMarks[i].bookMarkName + "  " + "</span><span>" + ' <a class="btn btn-primary mr-4" target="_blank" href="' + bookMarks[i].url + '">Visit</a> ' + "</span><span onclick='dD()'>" + ' <a class="btn btn-dengar mr-4" href="' + bookMarks[i].url + '">Delete</a> ' + "</span></div>"

    }

    document.getElementById("bookmarkCon").innerHTML = data;
}

function reset() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();

}


//Delete function

function dD() {

    for (var i = 0; i < bookMarks.length; i++) {
        if (bookMarks[i].url == bookMarks.url) {
            // Remove from array
            bookMarks.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}

console.log()
```

When I click the submit delete button, it transfer me to another error page.
How can i make a delete button work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Delete anchor tag's default behavior is set to navigate to the new page:

```
    <a class="btn btn-dengar mr-4" href="http://your-bookmark-url">Delete</a>
```

You obviously don't want to do that, so change the tag to a button:

```
    `<button class="btn btn-danger mr-4"
       onclick="handleDelete(${i});">Delete</button>`
```

Then set your Delete button's `handleDelete()` function to remove the bookmark and refresh the DOM:

```js
    function handleDelete(index) {
      // remove from bookMarks array
      bookMarks.splice(index, 1);
      // update the DOM
      displayData();
    }
```

Full working version:

```js
const bookMname = document.getElementById("siteName");
const bookUrl = document.getElementById("siteUrl");
const btn = document.getElementById("sub");
let bookMarks = [];

btn.onclick = function() {
  addBookMark();
  displayData();
  reset();
};

function addBookMark() {
  const bookMark = {
    bookMarkName: bookMname.value,
    url: bookUrl.value,
  };

  bookMarks.push(bookMark);
}

function displayData() {
  let data = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < bookMarks.length; i++) {
    data +=
      `<div>
          <span
            class="mr-5 font-weight-bold h1
              text-uppercase">${bookMarks[i].bookMarkName}</span>
          <a class="btn btn-primary mr-4"
            target="_blank"
            href="${bookMarks[i].url}">Visit</a>
          <button class="btn btn-danger mr-4"
            onclick="handleDelete(${i});">Delete</button>
        </div>`;
  }
  document.getElementById("bookmarkCon").innerHTML = data;
}

function reset() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}

function handleDelete(index) {
  bookMarks.splice(index, 1);
  displayData();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container pt-5 pb-5">
  <h1 class="pb-5 pl-3 font-weight-bold">BookMark</h1>
  <hr>
  <div class="body m-auto text-center py-5">
    <h2 class="py-2">Bookmark your favorite sites</h2>
    <form class="w-75 m-auto" id="myForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="siteName" class="py-2">Site Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="siteName" placeholder="Bookmark Name" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="siteUrl" class="py-2">Site URL</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="siteUrl" placeholder="website URL" required>
      </div>
      <button id="sub" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="container mt-3">
    <div class="row shadow-none p-3 mb-5 bg-light rounded">
      <!--dispalyarea-->
      <div class="col">
        <div id="bookmarkCon"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="footer">
    <p>&copy;2019 Bookmarker Inc.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks terrymorse, but how can i make the delete handleDelete () function , i made the below but it's not working ,  
function handleDelete() {

    return false;

}  , it's not delete anything

Comment: You still need to `// perform deletion and update DOM` in handleDelete(). I'll update the answer.